# MOSFET Channel Charge Density

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Suppose we have a n-channel MOSFET with source voltage \$V_S = 0V\$, bulk voltage \$V_B = 0 V\$, drain voltage \$V_D > V_S\$ and gate voltage \$V_G > V_T\$ where \$V_T\$ is the threshold voltage. If \$V_S = V_D\$, then the channel linear charge density is given by \$Q = C*(V_G-V_T)\$ where \$C\$ is the oxide capacity per unit area. If \$V_D > V_S\$, the voltage varies along the channel. The new expression for the channel linear charge density at position y along the channel should be \$Q(y) = C*(V_G-V(y)-V_T)\$ where \$V(y)\$ is the voltage at position \$y\$ along the channel. Why is that formula true? My professor derived the expression \$Q = C*(V_G-V_T)\$ by using the relation \$V_G - V_f = V_O + V_s\$ where \$V_f\$ is the flat-band voltage, \$V_O\$ is the voltage drop across the oxide and \$V_s\$ is the voltage drop across the depleted zone of the semiconductor. What's going on when the voltage varies along the channel? Is the flat-band voltage becoming a function of \$y\$?